# WTF? Zoom h4n rattle.

Tags: zoom-h4n, self-noise

So, my Rycote kit just showed up so I excitedly pulled out my h4n and connected everything, only to discover one annoying -- and apparently common from the factory -- thing about my h4n:  the record button and the stamina switch rattle when I shake it.

**Is there a better solution to stop this than tape?**

Comment: (not trying to be smart) Are you going to be shaking it while you record? How violently do you have to shake it to get it to make noise? 

Comment: Good point.  It's not at all present when it's stationary, but now that I have a pistol grip for it I can hear a faint click every time I change direction.

Comment: Have to love audio design flaws. Sort of like the Nikon D5100 coming out with an attachable mic to go where you place the external flash bulbs. Problem is, that camera has auto-focus in movie mode so all you'll hear is the little mechanical movements of the lens going in and out of focus. *shakes head*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Dave Matney,

Mine does, but I have to shake it pretty violently... does the Rycote rig make it worse? As a general rule, mine ALWAYS looks like an ad for Gorilla tape. It may not be elegant, but it is cheap and effective. Rick Viers seems to use a lot, judging from his videos. :) I DO make sure I take it off after every use, to keep the gunkys away.

Overall I love my H4n, but let's face it, it's not built to take the abuse we folks will probably heap on it (and WHAT'S WITH THE @#$%$ SD SLOT COVER!!!??) . You pays you're money and you takes your choice. Until I can get my own SD744, this will do :)

Comment: No, the Rycote doesn't make it worse -- I just hadn't used my h4n on a pistol grip until now.  The mic-adapter that they provided was similar to a pistol, but it had way too much handling noise.

Answer (score 4):

Place it on a cushion, serenade it with a violin and serve it grapes and sweet wine?   :D

Comment: And then send me the recording because I think it would sound good on a cushion near a violin. :)

Answer (score 2):

agreed.  Use some tape to tape down the stamina switch... or if you NEVER use the stamina switch, use some clear nail polish to have it stay in place.

Answer (score 2):

My Zoom H4n has also developed a rattle, but it appears to be coming from the cover to one of the mics which is ever-so-slightly loose. My fix has been to wedge a small rolled-up piece of gaffer tape between the two mics (where they cross over) with just enough pressure to hold the cover in place. It appears to work quite well.

Comment: picture of fix here: http://instagr.am/p/LsMyeCM2j7/

Answer (score 1):

I like the H4N for what it is but as a guitar player I have always known Zoom products to be cheaply constructed. No surprise there. I was reluctant to get on board with it because of Zoom's dismal reputation in the guitar processor market.